# Merging multiple rows into a single row using multiple indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have this dataset

```
FirstName    LastName    CourseName    CourseGrade
Joseph       Hanso       CS101         A+
Joseph       Hanso       CS102         D
....
```

And want it converted to this:

```
FirstName1    LastName1    CourseName1    CourseGrade1     CourseName2    CourseGrade2
Joseph       Hanso         CS101          A+               CS102          D
```

I'm not sure how to use `pd.pivot()` to do this. Are there any easy one liner to do this?

Comment: melt or stack .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
cols = ['FirstName', 'LastName']

out = (df
 # add new column with incremental count
 .assign(col=df.groupby(cols).cumcount().add(1).astype(str))
 # pivot using new col value as column level
 .pivot(index=cols, columns='col')
 # sort new column level
 .sort_index(level=1, axis=1, sort_remaining=False)
 # merge the 2 MultiIndex levels
 .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.map(''.join), axis=1))
 # index to columns
 .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
  FirstName LastName CourseName1 CourseGrade1 CourseName2 CourseGrade2
0    Joseph    Hanso       CS101           A+       CS102            D
```

Comment: I would highly appreciate if you add comments explaining each step